# Use Google Font with both the latin subset AND a special character

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm using google fonts to include the Ubuntu Mono font. I need the latin subset, and a special character (█). Google doesn't return this character with the font with or without a subset defined.

After looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#specifying_script_subsets) page I tried using `&text=█` in the url, which works!

However, it's not possible to combine the `subset=` and `text=` parameters, and I am thus unable to get the font to include both the standard subset AND the special character I require. Is it possible to get the API to return what I want?

Import for all common subsets: 
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Import for special character: 
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu+Mono:wght@400;700&text=█" rel="stylesheet">`

Import for both: 
`???`

Comment: The `text=[some specific language chars]` seems to be the way to go in probably both CSS(1) and CSS2 versions of the google webfonts. The `subset` parameter doesn't work for some reason, at least tested with CSS(1).

Comment: A paste from google's own docs "Note: there's no need to specify the `subset=` parameter when using `text=` as it allows you to refer to any character in the original font."